Setting up Eglot in Emacs 30
I am trying to use emacs for programming python and c/c++. I recently upgraded my MacOS setup to emacs-plus@30 --with-ctags--with-dbus --with-debug --with-mailutils --with-no-frame-refocus --with-xwidgets --with-imagemagick --with-native-comp --with-poll. Now everytime I open a python script, I get the message File mode specification error: (error Feature provided by other file: project). I am unsure if this is something specific to emacs 30 or if there is something wrong with the following script I have been trying to use:
(setq major-mode-remap-alist
      '((c-mode . c-ts-mode)
      (python-mode . python-ts-mode)
      (c++-mode-hook . c++-ts-mode)
      (c++-mode . c++-ts-mode)) )

(use-package eldoc
    :init
    (global-eldoc-mode))

(use-package eglot   :ensure nil   :hook ((python-base-mode c-ts-base-mode) . eglot-ensure))


Why not use a stable release of Emacs?

Same issue with emacs 29

Seems to be a bug in projectile, which is incorrectly listing "project" as a dependency, see this discussion https://github.com/radian-software/straight.el/issues/1146.
It was solved for me by explicitly loading project before eglot and projectile in my .emacs file:
...
(use-package project :straight t) ;; I added this line
...
(use-package projectile
  :straight t
  :ensure t
  :init
  (projectile-mode +1)
  :bind (:map projectile-mode-map
              ("s-p" . projectile-command-map)
              ("C-c p" . projectile-command-map)))

(use-package eglot :straight t :defer t)


I tried your suggestion, but I still have the same error.

I have the following in my configuration, but I still have the same error:
** Project
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(use-package project
  :straight t)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:

** Projectile

#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(use-package projectile
  :straight t
  :ensure t
  :init
  (projectile-mode)
  ;; NOTE: Set this to the folder where you keep your Git repos!
  (when (file-directory-p "~/Documents/Coding")
    (setq projectile-project-search-path '("~/Documents/Coding")))

  :bind-keymap
  ("C-c p" . projectile-command-map))

(setq savehist-additional-variables '(projectile-project-command-history))

(add-hook 'python-base-mode-hook
          (lambda () (setq-local projectile-project-run-cmd "python")))

(add-hook 'c-ts-mode-hook
          (lambda () (setq-local projectile-project-compilation-cmd
                 "cmake -B ./build/ && make -C ./build")))

(use-package treemacs-projectile
  :after (treemacs projectile)
  :straight t)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:

** Eglot
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
;; Optional, auto enable treesitter for python, c/c++
(setq major-mode-remap-alist
      '((c-mode . c-ts-mode)
        (python-mode . python-ts-mode)
        (c++-mode . c++-ts-mode))) 

(use-package eldoc
  :init
  (global-eldoc-mode))

(use-package eglot
  :straight t
  :defer t
  :hook ((python-ts-mode c++-ts-mode c-ts-mode) . eglot-ensure)
  :config
  (add-to-list 'eglot-server-programs
               '((python-ts-mode . ("pyright-langserver" "--stdio"))
                 (c-ts-mode c++-ts-mode . ("ccls")))))

#+end_src


This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review
